# How to find max and min reading from one list and corresponding day of max and min from another list (By using python 3.4)?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists which are given below.

```
reading = [4.19, 4.28, 6.90, 0.00, 8.26, 13.14, 11.75, 0.00, 16.83, 16.47, 15.26, 14.88]
day = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

And I want to find the maximum and minimum reading from the list “reading”. Same time I also need to find the corresponding day for max and min value from list “day”. The length of list “reading” is 12 while the length of list “day” is 13. Corresponding day of reading 4.19 is day 1, it means day count for reading starts from the second element of the list (day). I have tried below code to find the min and max value. But I am confused about the code to find out the corresponding day for min and max value. Any help regarding above-mentioned problem would be much appreciated.

Codes that I have tried to find max and min are as follows:

```
print ("Minimum reading is:", "%6.2f" % min(reading))
print ("maximum reading is:", "%6.2f" % max(reading))
```

So the possible output will be as follows:

```
Minimum reading is:   0.00
Corresponding Min Day is:  4, 11
maximum reading is:  16.83
Corresponding Max day is: 12
```

Comment: What attempts have you tried to solve this?

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question.

Comment: `sorted = sorted(zip(reading, day), key=lambda x: x[0]); print(sorted[0], sorted[-1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
reading = [4.19, 4.28, 6.90, 0.00, 8.26, 13.14, 11.75, 0.00, 16.83, 16.47, 15.26, 14.88]
day = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

min_reading = min(reading)
max_reading = max(reading)
min_days = [str(d) for d, r in zip(day[1:], reading) if r == min_reading]
max_days = [str(d) for d, r in zip(day[1:], reading) if r == max_reading]

print ("Minimum reading is:", "%6.2f" % min(reading))
print ("Corresponding Min Day is:  %s" % ', '.join(min_days))
print ("maximum reading is:", "%6.2f" % max(reading))
print ("Corresponding Max Day is:  %s" % ', '.join(max_days))
```

Notes:

- Use the built-in `max()` and `min()` functions to find the extrema.
- Since you can have multiple minima and maxima, you'll need to construct a list to hold them. I used a list comprehension to do that.
- The `zip()` function establishes a correlation between the readings and days. This makes mapping the readings to days possible.
- `day[1:]`  represents the list of valid days, since the `day` list starts with an offset of 1.
- It is okay to convert the day values to strings using the `str()` constructor since the program only subsequently requires strings. If the real program requires integer values later, this won't work.

If I had to do this in one pass (because, for example, the datasets are very large or because it is a homework requirement), I would write my own loop instead of calling `min()` and `max()`:

```
min_reading = float('inf')
max_reading = float('-inf')
min_days = []
max_days = []

for d, r in zip(day[1:], reading):
    if r < min_reading:
        min_reading = r
        min_days = [d]
    elif r == min_reading:
        min_days.append(d)
    if r > max_reading:
        max_reading = r
        max_days = [d]
    elif r == max_reading:
        max_days.append(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `numpy` solution.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> reading = np.array([4.19, 4.28, 6.90, 0.00, 8.26, 13.14, 11.75, 0.00, 16.83, 16.47, 15.26, 14.88])
>>> day = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])[1:]
>>> 
>>> min_ = np.min(reading)
>>> min_
0.0
>>> day[reading == min_]
array([ 4, 11])
>>> 
>>> max_ = np.max(reading)
>>> max_
16.829999999999998
>>> day[reading == max_]
array([12])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arg_min = 0
min = reading[arg_min]
for i in range(0,len(reading)):
    if reading[i] < min:
        arg_min = i
        min = reading[i]
```

After that, the `arg_min` is the index of the minimum reading... therefore it's the index of the day with the minimum reading as well.